# FlushFinalBlock increases bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

So basically as the titles say, I just have a question regarding the FlushFinalBlock. Why my encrypted data from the original byte size it's increasing by 16bytes when it hits the FlushFinalBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most encryptions work with blocks of a fixed size.

FlushFinalBlock() will have to pad the last data segment up to a full blocksize.

The exact number will depend on the encryption type and the blocksize. The padding details are also a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, thought had something wrong with my encryption because I'm receiving a 'bad length' in the decryption

Comment: The thing is that I'm using Hybrid encryption and the key is 32bytes which becomes 128 and the iv is 16 which becomes 128 total = 256+file size, then in the decryption reading both in 128 bytes but I'm having a 'bad length' error. When I change the decryption to reading 86bytes it doesnt appear....

Comment: Not all cipher modes or ciphers work with blocks of fixed size. Actually, only (P)CBC and ECB work that way, and stream ciphers obviously do not use a block. Similarly, only those modes require padding - and they also might use cipher text stealing. So I'm not sure I agree with the start of this answer. OTOH, it seems very likely that this is what happens for this specific question.

Comment: I can't follow the details. If you want help, post a [mcve] type of quesyion. @Toy99

Comment: @Maarten - I don't see streamcyphers used much, and the OP already mentioned an IV.

Comment: FlushFinalBlock belongs to the CryptoStream and that uses a block cypher.

Comment: @Toy99 That's a *different* kind of streaming for I/O operations :) It has little to do with stream ciphers (other than that streams ciphers nicely match the logic of streaming, which makes buffering / blocking issues a non-issue). That .NET doesn't include CTR is probably a mistake, and they *are* used a lot, for instance as underlying cipher in almost any kind of AEAD cipher (CCM, GCM) and modern transport protocols.

Comment: We need more details, "32 bytes become 128" for hybrid encryption, probably the key is wrapped with RSA-1024 - that would make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks, but what will be most likely to be the problem causing 'bad length' if it's encrypted as supposed returning 256+the size of the file and in the decryption, I'm reading the symmetric key and IV both of 128 bytes? Also, the problem is becing occurred when calling the Asymmetric Decryption(privatekey, key).

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Yes it's being wrapped by RSA. Can someone invite me in a room so I discuss since I'm low reputation...

Comment: So anyway, you mentioned the RSA, yes it wrapped in an RSA key.I've read that by 1024 it should read an 86bytes key. I've tried switching it to 86bytes and it worked. So, 1024 RSA doesnt read 128 bytes ?